# Can anyone explain to me what the advantage is of the current Child Parent location is?

Tags: parent, linked-data, coordinates

Almost in every other apllication that uses a coordinate system with a world origin, the basic principle of a child parent relationship is: the parent becomes the child world origin. In blender when you parent an object, the transform(position,rotation,scale) stays the same, even more against every basic logic, when you move the parent, the transform of the child object stays the same, I know there are workarounds, but for me and many others that come from other 3d packages this makes even the most simple rigs very backward and a pain to work with. So can anyone give an answer other then : "this is how blender works"

First of all, blender is awesome, but if this isn't fixed in the future then I fear blender will never become an industry standard beyond basic asset creation.

Comment: The answer to your question is going to be the answer to this question: What were the Blender Devs thinking? I don't know. You might want to ask them. From what I hear, they're quite accessible compared to the devs of other 3D software programs. So far as I can tell, Blender seems to want you to construct everything at the worldspace origin. If you're adamant about doing that, you can get similar functionality to what you describe from other packages by simply applying the transforms of the child object. That is, provided the parent object is at the worldspace origin when you do it.

Comment: The coordinates you see that are "not changing" are the local coordinates.  Can assure you the world matrix of child objects `ob.matrix_world`  changes when transforming parents.   To parent an object (let's say the default cube at identity) to the lamp or camera if you choose the without inverse option when parenting, the cube will move to the transform of the parent.  The world matrix calculation can involve  constraints. Editing a constrained objects matrix world could produce unexpected results which among other things may explain the global option not being available in the transforms.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 types of assigning a parent you might be interested in:

[image]

regular one:
[image]

and keep transform one:
[image]

as you can see both have a 0.1 vector transform but they are not positioned the same from the parent.

read more about it here:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html

Answer (score -1):

It would be great to have the option of setting 'keep transforms without inverse' as the default parent behaviour when using the outliner.

Comment: Please don't add comments in the answer field!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/183338)